# Moving Javascript Out of Template Files

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP applications I'm forking which contains a lot of inline javascript in the view files. I'm assuming the reason for this is that quite often the inline script contains php variables passed to the view by the controller.

I want to be able to remove the javascript from the view files and place them into separate files, yet still be able to parse the php in the files.

I have an existing Document class so I added a method `renderScript` so that I can pass in the needed file:

```
public function renderScript($script) {
    $this->scripts[md5($script)] = $this->script_directory . $script;
}
```

Then my intention is to build a controller that can be called that will iterate through any added scripts, parsing the php, then added it to the dom.

In my controller:

```
public function index() {
    $scripts = $this->document->getScripts();

    $files = '';

    foreach ($scripts as $key => $value):
        $files .= file_get_contents ($value); 
    endforeach;

    $data['script'] = $files;

    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

    return $this->load->view('common/javascript', $data);
}
```

Then in my view:

```
<script>
<?= $script; ?>
</script>
```

I then load the controller into my footer controller:

```
$data['javascript'] = $this->load->controller('common/javascript');
```

This works sort of ... in that it does echo the entire file into the footer of my app, but that's not really what I want.

I'd rather be able to simply use a script tag in my footer view to call the controller directly, but this doesn't work since the javascript controller is passed through index.php and is dispatched and the document reset.

So ... is there a way I can include these js files, parse the php in them, and then add them to the dom without printing the entire content to the rendered html?

I'm sure there's way, I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Mixing php and js is rarely a good idea. Better to either add data to `data-` attributes and retrieve it with js, or create an ajax controller that returns data as json, and call that with ajax

Comment: I agree it's rarely a good idea, but I really don't have a choice, there's FAR too many files with major javascript to try to tackle all this at once.  Eventually I'll port the entire app to Angular, but for now, one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well i dont see a nice way of doing what you want.

If the script is in a separate file, it is loaded in a separate get request, meaning none of the data from the controller will be available to it, as you have already discovered.

If you intend to move to full JS frontend (Angular) with php json backend, then this intermediary step seems fairly pointless, just stick with inline js whilst you make the change to angular.

That said, here is a (not great) solution:

in your main controller, just before you render the view, dump all the data you need for js into session:

```
$_SESSION['jsData']=array(...);
```

create a javascript controller, that renders the js with the data:

```
function renderJs($script){

    $jsData = $_SESSION['jsData'];
    $this->view->render($script, $jsData, 'application/javascript');
```

Add the script tag in your view:

```
<script src=/jcontroller/renderjs/somescript.php
```

Note the js files have a php extension so php vars can be interpreted in your view->render function